# Connection to a MS SQL database from Google scripts

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc, google-apps-script, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL database (2012) using google script using the JDBC service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

I'm having issues connecting and keep getting the message 
'Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. (line 4, file "Code")'

I have setup the port and followed the instructions from the website above. Here is the statement below that I am using:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://<ip>:<port>;databaseName=<db name>;user=<user>;password=<password>");
```

Does anyone see anything wrong. I keep reading about needing the JDBC driver installed on the MS SQL server, do I need to call it in the script somewhow?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm stuck with the same issue. What driver did you install?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Didn't need a driver. What I had above was correct. On the MS SQL server, I had the sql username and password set as 'Change on next Logon'. so I unchecked this. Make sure your firewall and port settings are correct.

Check the Event log on the server. This is how I found out that it was connecting and it was a username/password issue.

Comment: Thank you, I think my firewall settings are wrong, and I don't have admin rights, so will need to go through my IT dept

Answer (score 1):

i got same error but now resolved after doing following things :

var conn =  Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;databaseName={dbname};user={user@hostname};password={passowrd@hostname};");

and whit-list following ip on firewall :

64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255 
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255 
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255 66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255 72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255 74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255 173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255 207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255 209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255 216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255

Answer (score 0):

Google Scripts and Azure SQL Server worked for me with this:

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:sqlserver://**your-server**.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=**your-db-name**;user=**username**@**your-catalog**;password=**yourpassword**;');
  Logger.log(conn);

So you got to take JSBC connection string from Azure and replace portion of that string: instead of: 
...1433;database=... 
in Google Script you should have:
...1433;databaseName=

**your-catalog** for me is the same as **your-server**.database.windows.net

Comment: If you want to have public access to your DB from everywhere just do the range 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 but don't forget to change it to a proper white list including Google specified ranges https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections